# How to add expiry or future date in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Is there a way to add/change some code in this jQuery to show the date expire after some months or years that I specified?

For example, I designed a Membership Card for a client and this Membership Card is valid for 2 year and I want the script to add expire date.

Thank you

```
jQuery("#cd").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/M/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '2015:' + new Date().getFullYear(),
    altField: "#acd",
    altFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the date by calling the setDate option like

```
$( "#cd" ).datepicker("setDate", "+1y");
```

The second argument can be a number - denoting the number of days from now, or a string with "y" "m" and "d" suffixes like `"+1y +5m"`.